# Web to Arduino serial communication

Tags: java, serialization, processing, arduino, processing.js

I am looking to transfer commands/data from a web-page to an Arduino in order to interact with it in the same way you would on a local computer. I have done this with [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) and am just beginning to read into `processing.js` for a possible solution. As it stands it looks like I may have to utilize a 'middle-man' for server-side (like node.js or Ajax) to grab the information from both client-side and the Arduino, to then be processed.

I was hoping to get clarification on this; the different options available to achieve this with some possible links, small examples or whatever you feel would best aid me. I do not necessarily need to utilize `processing.js`, I am comfortable with most client-side web stuff.

Comment: I have solved this, sort of... I am currently utilizing Ajax to retrieve and then pass variables to a PHP script which then utilizes the PHP serial class to send information to the server's serial port which is connected to the Arduino. This works quite well because of Ajax, I can issue multiple commands. I am now thinking of creating a processing.js webpage which can take more detailed co-ordinate based information (required for the type of project I am pursuing) and relay it server-side via the Ajax->PHP->serial configuration I currently have. Is processing.js really the best way to do this,

Comment: or are there more efficient and powerful alternatives? Would Python provide me with what I am looking for (I know of it, but I have not used it yet, so this would be a great excuse to do so)? Aside from Python, what other options are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Python with pySerial library. Very easy to use, and definitely faster than Processing/Arduino app.

Comment: Would this allow me to communicate with an arduino that resides on the server side via remote web access (client side)?

Comment: I believe it would. There are already existing web-frameworks for python, and you can make one yourself easily as well. The code will need to be ran by CGI.

Comment: Great! I have never used python, but this is the perfect excuse to delve into its world. I did some reading, and you knowledge is exactly that! My current solution (the post under this one) works, but is wildly limited.